# Browser or server version of module

Tags: dependencies, requirejs, shared, amd

Using requirejs and javascript modules, i'd like to share code between server and browser, there are four situations.

1/ module only for server

```
define([], function() {
   if(typeof window != 'undefined') return null; // only for server
   //module code
})
```

2/ module only for browser

```
define([], function() {
   if(typeof window == 'undefined') return null; // only for browser
   //module code
})
```

3/ module shared

```
define([], function() {
   //module code
})
```

4/ module with different code for server/browser

```
define(['require'], function(require) {
   if(typeof window == 'undefined') // server version
   {
      return require('nodejs module');
   }

   // browser version
})
```

What i want to solve better way is including module code for browser, now i have to past whole code of browser version. Nodejs require is sync, it works. But in browser i have to use something like

```
define(['require'], function(require) {
   if(typeof window == 'undefined') // server version
   {
      return require('nodejs_module');
   }

   require(['module_for_browser'], function(module_for_browser) {
      return module_for_browser;
   })
}
```

but i can't return it!

Most libraries have same code for both and manage this internally checking window, but some not. Now i want to use same eventemitter api for server require('events').EventEmitter and for browser this compatible version https://github.com/hij1nx/EventEmitter2